# Extrema and inflection points for $x^3 - 3x^2 + kx$

Tags: calculus, algebraic-curves

My girlfriend has a problem with her math task. I did all this stuff years ago when so I am pretty behind and clueless what to do. She has following function:
$x^3 - 3x^2 +kx $$

Her tasks are following:

a) Analyze the function for $k = 1,$ $k = -1$ and $k = 0.$

b) Prove that all the functions $f_{k}$ have the same inflection point.

c) Analyze how $k$ influences the relative maxima and minima of $f_k.$

Comment: what is a "watershed"?  I can't understand c at all

Comment: Thank you very much for that edit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one of the roots of this function is $0$, since we can factor out the $x$ this leaves us with
$$x(x^2-3x+k)$$
the other roots can easily be found via discriminant.

The derrivative is
$$3x^2-6x+k$$
the zeroes of it(which can be found via discriminant once again) correspond to the original functions relative maxima and minima.

The second derrivative is
$$6x-6$$
since the free member $k$ become zero with derivation, and since the second derivatives zeroes are the inflection points of the function, we can say that the point of inflection is not affected by $k$.

Comment: This is a in general hint type of answer, you are left to analyze a) and c) on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I will hand that out to her